# Rails: encode field before saving and decode after retrieving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Rails and I'm working with legacy code. There are models with properties that aren't encoded in the most efficient format for storage. I want to encode the properties before saving to the database and decode them when I retrieve them. Since lots of code expects the properties to be in the inefficient format, I can't just change the model to the more efficient format.

Specifically, the model stores polygons on a map as an array of objects: `[{lat: 0, lng: 0}, ...]`. A lot of the code expects this format, I don't want to change all the code because I'll probably break something. In the database, the polygons should be stored as encoded polylines (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm). How can I store the data in the database as encoded polylines, but make the code see the model's properties as arrays of objects?

Comment: Do you have functions which can encode and decode the polyline as a plain data object? If so, you can override the getter/setter methods to use JSON serialization.

Comment: `before_save` and `after_initialize` are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @JoshBrody apparently, `before_save` would make the property dirty? Do you know if this would be an issue?

Comment: "I don't want to change all the code because I'll probably break something." When working with legacy code you really need to start by adding tests that verify that existing features work and that you're not causing regressions. The hard part is just getting your boss / client to understand that adding features to a legacy app is often more work.